# Replace Zeros in Cell Range for Multiple Worksheets w/Non-Specific Worksheet names or Number of Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I would like to clear cells where value = 0 in a specific range across mutliple worksheets. The number and names of worksheets will be different every time the macro is run. This is what I came up with, but it's not working.

```
'
' REMOVEZERO_KVEMoxyModel Macro
'
'

Sub REMOVEZERO_KVEMoxyModel()


     Dim ws As Worksheet
     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     Call RemoveZeros


 End Sub

 Sub RemoveZeros()


  For Each cell In Range("I3:I500")
  If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: please upload the rest of your code, you are missing an `Next cell` at the end. and also `Next ws` at the first `Sub`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Shai. I made the changes but it only worked for the first worksheet in the workbook. Do you have any further suggestions?'
' REMOVEZERO_KVEMoxyModel Macro
'
'

Sub REMOVEZERO_KVEMoxyModel()
     
     
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     Call RemoveZeros
     Next ws
     
     
 End Sub
 
 Sub RemoveZeros()
 

  For Each cell In Range("I3:I500")
  If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear
  Next cell
  
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below: it will loop through all worksheets in `ActiveWorkbook`. In this example, if `Sheet.Name = "Sheet1"` or `Sheet.Name = "Sheet2"` (using the `Select Case`) then it will go inside and clear all the "0" from the `Range` you specified.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub REMOVEZERO_KVEMoxyModel()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        ' only run the clear "0" cells in "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" >> modify according to your needs
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
            Call RemoveZeros(ws)

    End Select
Next ws

End Sub

Sub RemoveZeros(sht As Worksheet)

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In sht.Range("I3:I500")
   If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.ClearContents
Next cell

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: clear the "0" cells for all worksheets (removed the `Select Case ws.Name` as it's not needed)

```
Sub REMOVEZERO_KVEMoxyModel()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call RemoveZeros(ws)            
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. The Excel spreadsheet is exported from an application and the sheet names and number of sheets will change each time I need to use the macro. Is there a way to select all the worksheets?I appreciate your help.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for your help. You have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Mcurrier you're welcome, please mark as answer, by putting the little **V** next to my answer